# Increasing HTML form size

Tags: html, css

For the HTML form below, the entry field, button, and entry text all seem to be about 12 px.  What is the best method of increasing them all?  I think I'd like to have them at about 14 px.

```
<div class="searchbox2">
    <form action="sitesearch.php" method="get">
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="name="find" size="55"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.searchbox2 input {
    font-size: 14px
}
```

Comment: the `.` in `.input` implies a class-name of 'input', whereas he's trying to target the *input* element.

Answer (score 1):

```
input {font-size: 14px; }
```

But please don't do that. Use ems, or or ex, to size fonts. Otherwise your forms are at the mercy of the resolution of the monitor's display. Ems, or whatever, aren't necessarily perfect, but they're a slightly less fragile means of sizing fonts without, on the user zooming the page, breaking layout.
input

```
input {font-size: 14px; }
```

Or, for all text within the form:

```
form {font-size: 1.4em; }
```

Where the 1.4 will be calculated from the parent of the form.